# Pass link URL variable to javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a link that people can put on their own websites that links back to their profile on my site.

I have created the 'widget' using javascript so have a .js file that simplified does this...

```
document.write("Visit my profile at...");
document.write("    <a href=\"myprofilelink.html\">Click To View</a>");
```

I want to be able to create a call to it that automatically includes the profile link in the javascript so for example, something like....

```
<script src="widget.js" id="myprofilelink.html></script>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a variable before including your widget script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var profileLink = "myprofilelink.html";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget.js"></script>
```

Then you can just use the variable in your widget.js file:

```
document.write("<a href=\"" + profileLink + "\">Click To View</a>");
```

If you want to learn about how to work with more advanced JavaScript widgets I'd recommend reading [Developing An Embeddable Javascript Widget](http://www.shootitlive.com/2012/07/developing-an-embeddable-javascript-widget/).

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.  Thanks for the further reading as well :)